# Как преобразовать вложенные структуры JSON на Python

Tags: python, json

Нужно получить данные по территориям: Страна, область,город из hh.ru (https://api.hh.ru/areas).
В ответе приходят данные формата JSON с вложенными в друг друга структурой данных.
Получилось написать такой код, который преобразует первый вложенный запрос в таблицу.
Но теперь не могу обработать оставшиеся вложенные структуры.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize


response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.hh.ru/areas')
str_response = response.read().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(str_response)


s=json.dumps(obj)
s2=json.loads(s)

response_json_norm =json_normalize(s2)

areas_with_id = s2
for i in areas_with_id:
    is_areas = i.get('areas')
    if not is_areas:
        areas_with_id.remove(i)

areas_with_id_n = json_normalize(areas_with_id,
                                 record_path='areas',
                                 meta='parent_id',
                                 record_prefix='areas.',
                                 errors="ignore")


response_json_norm.drop(['areas'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
summary = response_json_norm.merge(areas_with_id_n, how='outer')


df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(summary)
# df.to_excel("C:\Vacancy\Vacancy_areas.xlsx")
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: Я уже нашел в интернете, что если вы хотите перебрать и вложенные значения, вам нужно написать рекурсивную функцию, которая может перебирать этот древовидный запрос json. Но мои скудные знания не позволяют это сделать...

Comment: Нужна обычная таблица со столбцами и строками для импорта в PostgreSQL.

Comment: Попробуйте это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269285/5741205

Comment: Зачем такие хитрые пляски, чтобы получить `json` с `url`? Достаточно `requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/areas').json()` и всё, не надо никаких `decode` и `json.loads`, сразу готовый словарь уже.